# Opening php file in mymodal box and passing a variable to it

Tags: php, jquery, variables, modal-dialog

I have a modal box that opens content from the footer of a page (a hidden div). I am trying to launch the modal and display the content of another .php file whilst passing a variable that can be used to SELECT from a DB Any ideas?

Here is the code:

The modal box link

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>
```

The JS

```
(function($) {
 $('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
    $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
});
```

The .php file with the modalbox content

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
 <div>content called from DB using passed variable</div>
 <p>more content</p>
 <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
```

Does anyone have any ideas please?

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATED!
Here is the full js file:

```
(function($) {


$('a[data-reveal-id').live('click', function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');

$.ajax({
    url: 'code.php',
    data: '$varible', 
    type: 'GET', 
    error: function()
    {
        // If there's an issue, display an error...
    },
    success: function(output)
    {
        $('#' + modalLocation).innerHTML(output).reveal( $(this).data() );
    }
});
})


$.fn.reveal = function(options) {


    var defaults = {  
        animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
        animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
        closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
    }; 


    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

    return this.each(function() {


        var modal = $(this),
            topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
            topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
            locked = false,
            modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');


        if(modalBG.length == 0) {
            modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
        }           

        //Entrance Animations
        modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
          modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
            $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
            if(!locked) {
                lockModal();
                if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                    modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                        "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                        "opacity" : 1
                    }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                }
                if(options.animation == "fade") {
                    modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                        "opacity" : 1
                    }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                } 
                if(options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                    modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                    unlockModal()               
                }
            }
            modal.unbind('reveal:open');
        });     

        //Closing Animation
        modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
          if(!locked) {
                lockModal();
                if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                    modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                    modal.animate({
                        "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                        "opacity" : 0
                    }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                        modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                        unlockModal();
                    });                 
                }   
                if(options.animation == "fade") {
                    modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                    modal.animate({
                        "opacity" : 0
                    }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                        modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                        unlockModal();
                    });                 
                }   
                if(options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                    modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
                }       
            }
            modal.unbind('reveal:close');
        });     


        //Open Modal Immediately
    modal.trigger('reveal:open')

        //Close Modal Listeners
        var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
          modal.trigger('reveal:close')
        });

        if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
            modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
            modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
              modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });
        }
        $('body').keyup(function(e) {
            if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
        });


        function unlockModal() { 
            locked = false;
        }
        function lockModal() {
            locked = true;
        }   

    });//each call
}//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the html trigger:

```
<a class="big-link" href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me to open modal</a>
```

Here is the code.php, file containing the modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal"><div>content called from DB using passed variable</div><p>more content</p><a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
```

The issue at the minute is not passing the variable, but actually lauching the modal with the content of code.php

Thanks again for your time with this problem!

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to make an Ajax call to the PHP file, and then output the data into your `myModal` div. Have you looked at jQuery's [Ajax info](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)?

Comment: This sounds promising, however im not sure how you would go about working it in to this code?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what variables you're looking to pass, and what you're trying to grab, you can modify this. I haven't tested it so you may have to do some tweaking.

```
$('a[data-reveal-id').live('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'URL_TO_YOUR_PHP',
        data: 'YOUR_VARIABLE', // Look at how to pass data using GET, or POST
        type: 'GET' or 'POST', // Choose one, and pass the data above appropriately
        error: function()
        {
            // If there's an issue, display an error...
        },
        success: function(output)
        {
            $('#' + modalLocation).innerHTML(output).reveal( $(this).data() );
        }
    });
})
```

-- EDIT --

Now the problem is that you don't have `#myModal` available in your HTML, yet. So, what you want to do is change the following line accordingly:

```
$('#' + modalLocation).innerHTML(output).reveal( $(this).data() );
-- BECOMES --
$("body").append(output).reveal( $(this).data() );
```

In your CSS you'll want to initially hide your modal box that way it's *revealed* appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for this, I shall test this and report back.

Comment: Hi Kacey,  I have tested this code and using chrome dev audit tool I am getting the error Uncaught type error: undefined is not a function. Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing all of your code it's impossible for me to tell what the problem could be. Sorry. You can update your question with your new code, and we can go from there.

Comment: ah ha, were getting somewhere this looks promising, I will play around with this. Once again thank you very much for your help!!!